# How to write a custom value change event handler in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, asp.net-blazor

I want to write a custom drop down list component for Blazor partly due to the fact that the existing InputSelect component does not bind to anything other than string and enum types. This is not good enough for me since my models have int and nullable int type properties that I want bound to the drop down list. So far I have this:

```
@using System.Globalization

@typeparam TValue
@typeparam TData

@inherits InputBase<TValue>

<select id="@Id" @bind="CurrentValueAsString" class="f-select js-form-field">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OptionLabel) || Value == null)
    {
        <option value="">@(OptionLabel ?? "-- SELECT --")</option>
    }
    @foreach (var item in Data)
    {
        <option value="@GetPropertyValue(item, ValueFieldName)">@GetPropertyValue(item, TextFieldName)</option>
    }
</select>
<span>Component Value is: @Value</span>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TData> Data { get; set; } = new List<TData>();

    [Parameter]
    public string ValueFieldName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string TextFieldName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string OptionLabel { get; set; }

    private Type ValueType => IsValueTypeNullable() ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TValue)) : typeof(TValue);

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        ValidateInitialization();
    }

    private void ValidateInitialization()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ValueFieldName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ValueFieldName), $"Parameter {nameof(ValueFieldName)} is required.");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextFieldName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(TextFieldName), $"Parameter {nameof(TextFieldName)} is required.");
        }
        if (!HasProperty(ValueFieldName))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Data type {typeof(TData)} does not have a property called {ValueFieldName}.");
        }
        if (!HasProperty(TextFieldName))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Data type {typeof(TData)} does not have a property called {TextFieldName}.");
        }
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out TValue result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        if (ValueType == typeof(string))
        {
            result = (TValue)(object)value;
            return true;
        }
        if (ValueType == typeof(int))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                result = default;
            }
            else
            {
                if (int.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var parsedValue))
                {
                    result = (TValue)(object)parsedValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = default;
                    validationErrorMessage = $"Specified value cannot be converted to type {typeof(TValue)}";
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        if (ValueType == typeof(Guid))
        {
            validationErrorMessage = null;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                result = default;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Guid.TryParse(value, out var parsedValue))
                {
                    result = (TValue)(object)parsedValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = default;
                    validationErrorMessage = $"Specified value cannot be converted to type {typeof(TValue)}";
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{GetType()} does not support the type '{typeof(TValue)}'. Supported types are string, int and Guid.");
    }

    private string GetPropertyValue(TData source, string propertyName)
    {
        return source.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.GetValue(source, null).ToString();
    }

    private bool HasProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        return typeof(TData).GetProperty(propertyName) != null;
    }

    private bool IsValueTypeNullable()
    {
        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TValue)) != null;
    }

}
```

And in the parent component I can use it like this:

```
<DropDownList Id="@nameof(Model.SelectedYear)"
    @bind-Value="Model.SelectedYear"
    Data="Model.Years"
    ValueFieldName="@nameof(Year.Id)"
    TextFieldName="@nameof(Year.YearName)">
</DropDownList>
```

This works very well, the model binds to the drop down list and the value is changed on the parent model when the drop down list value is changed. However I now want to capture this value change event on my parent and do some custom logic, mainly load some additional data based on the selected year. My guess is that I need a custom EventCallback but everything I tried causes some sort of build or runtime error. It seems that if my component inherits from InputBase then I am very much limited in what I can do.

Can anyone tell me how can I capture the value change from a child component in a parent component?

Comment: Why not derive from InputText ?

Comment: @enet I need to render HTML select tag not input type text. I actually tried to inherit from InputSelect unsuccessfully because it only handles string and enum binding - fails when you try to bind to a property of any other type.

Comment: Is your code working ? See my answer sample... This is how you should do it with other types if needed.

Comment: @enet Yeah my code is working. I did not try yours but it seems resonable. I supose I could've done it like that but I don't like the idea of having to generate option tags myself via some sort of loop. I wanted the component to do that for me too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My guess is that I need a custom EventCallback

You sure need a `EventCallback`, but the thing is, you already have one, just don't see it.

To be able to use `@bind-Value` you need two parameters, `T Value` and `EventCallback<T> ValueChanged`.

When you pass `@bind-Foo`, blazor sets these two parameters, `Foo` and `FooChanged` and in the `FooChanged` it will simply set the new value to `Foo`.

So when you do `@bind-Foo="Bar"` what blazor does under the hood is pass these two parameters

```
Foo="@Bar"
FooChanged="@(newValue => Bar = newValue)"
```

So in your case, what you need to do is pass your own `ValueChanged` function, that sets the new value in `Value` but also do some extra things you want.

```
<DropDownList Id="@nameof(Model.SelectedYear)"
    Value="Model.SelectedYear"
    ValueChanged="@((TYPE_OF_VALUE newValue) => HandleValueChanged(newValue))"
    Data="Model.Years"
    ValueFieldName="@nameof(Year.Id)"
    TextFieldName="@nameof(Year.YearName)">
</DropDownList>

@code 
{
    void HandleValueChanged(TYPE_OF_VALUE newValue)
    {
        // do what you want to do 

        // set the newValue if you want
        Model.SelectedYear = newValue;
    }
}
```

In `TYPE_OF_VALUE`, you just replace it with the type of `Model.SelectedYear`.

You can take a look at this explanation in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#child-to-parent-binding-with-chained-bind).

## Edit

Because you want to use nullable types, you also need to pass `FooExpression` which in your case will be `Expression<Func<T>> ValueExpression`.

```
<DropDownList Id="@nameof(Model.SelectedYear)"
    Value="Model.SelectedYear"
    ValueChanged="@((TYPE_OF_VALUE newValue) => HandleValueChanged(newValue))"
    ValueExpression="@(() => Model.SelectedYear)"
    Data="Model.Years"
    ValueFieldName="@nameof(Year.Id)"
    TextFieldName="@nameof(Year.YearName)">
</DropDownList>
```

Comment: Yeah I thought that too, but when I add ValueChanged="MyChangeHandler" and then create that handler with a single parameter of type nullable int I get the following compile error: "Argument 2: Cannot convert from method group to EventCallback". After more research found that I need to do this: ValueChanged="@((int? param) => HandleValueChanged(param))." Can you update your answer and I'll accept it as correct?

Comment: You get "Argument 2: Cannot convert from method group to EventCallback", but how you defined `MyChangeHandler`? And there is a difference between `ValueChanged="MyChangeHandler"` without `@` and `ValueChanged="@MyChangeHandler"` with `@`. Please show me how you defined `MyChangeHandler`

Comment: Whether I include @ or not makes no difference the error is the same. The handler is defined as: private void HandleValueChanged(int? newValue)
    {
        Model.SelectedClassYear = newValue;
    }

Comment: Based on https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12226 it's a known issue I guess.

Comment: @Marko Based on [this response](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12226#issuecomment-514346015) to the issue, you need to pass `ValueExpression` to the component, which is also another thing that blazor creates when using `@bind-` and it's required because you are passing an nullable property. I will update my answer with that information

Comment: Yup you are correct I do need the ValueExpression directive. It works now I can confirm it.